# Perl int to array

Tags: perl

I have a number stored in a Perl variable and I want to 'pass/convert/store' its digits in the different positions of an array. An example for a better sight:

I have, let's say, this number stored:

```
$hello = 429384
```

And I need a new array with the digits stored in it, so:

```
$hello2[0] = 4
$hello2[1] = 2
$hello2[2] = 9
Etc..
```

I can probably make it with a couple of loops, but I want to know if there is an efficient and fast way to do it. Thx in advance!

Comment: Perl arrays normally start at 0.  Are you sure you want the first digit in `$hello2[1]`?  What goes in `$hello2[0]`?

Comment: Yeah, first one is 0, i was just pointing to the method to parse it to the array automatically instead of one by one =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my @hello = split //, $hello;
```

In Perl if you use number in a string operator, the conversion is done automatically

Comment: The first argument to `split` should be a regex, so please use `split //, $hello`, not `split '', $hello`.

Comment: @davecross No it does not have to. Please check perldoc for your reference

Comment: I didn't say it had to, I said it should be. It is interpreted as a regular expression, so putting it in `/.../` makes people realise that. This is advice based on many years of experience fixing code from people who have forgotten this.

Comment: @DaveCross I agree with you it will be more clear that way, but the perldoc here http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html just uses empty quoted string and I think if one does not know it, he should not use it.

Comment: Good point. I'll see if I can get that documentation changed.

Answer (score 5):

```
$hello = 429384;

@hello = split //, $hello;

print $hello[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only Regex and without using any inbuilt function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string=429384;

my @numbers = $string =~ /./g; # dot matches a single character at a time 
                               #and returns it 

print "@numbers \n";
```

Comment: Why do you think that regexes are not a built-in function? And why print a space before the newline?

Comment: I think `=~` is more like an operator than a function.Space is not intentional.IMHO it doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

this is significantly faster than the regexp way:

```
  $string = '1234567890';
  $_-=48 for @digits = unpack 'C*',$string;
```

benchmark:

```
use Time::HiRes;
$string = '1234567890';



$start_time = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];
for (1.. 100000){
  $_-=48 for @digits= unpack 'C*',$string;
}
$diff = Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start_time);
print "\n\n$diff\n";



$start_time = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];
for (1.. 100000){
  @digits = split //, $string;
}
$diff = Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start_time);
print "\n\n$diff\n";
```

output:

> 0.265814
>
> 0.314735